# Raspberry images while booting

Tags: boot

When my B+ boots up it has one raspberry on the top left of the screen. When my Raspberry 2 B boots up it has 3 raspberries. What do these raspberries mean?

Answer (score 8):

The berries indicate the number of CPU cores in the processor.  You should actually be seeing 4 of them.

That is why the B+ only has one - it's single core.